# How can I convert a list of dicts showing hierarchical relationships into a tree?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, hierarchical-data

I have this list of dicts:

```
[
    {"node": "root", "children": ["a"]},
    {"node": "a", "children": ["b", "b"]},
    {"node": "b", "children": ["c", "c", "c"]},
    {"node": "c", "children": ["d"]},
]
```

that represents a compressed tree. What I mean by that is this list of dict represents the following tree:

[image: example uncompressed tree]

What kind of a data structure can I convert this list of dict into so I can expand it into a tree? I was thinking of unrolling the list of dicts to something like:

```
{"root": [
    {"a": [
        {"b": [
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            },
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            },
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {"b": [
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            },
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            },
            {"c": [
                {"d": "None"}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Looks messy, but essentially a nested dict of nodes to list of children. Not really sure how to achieve this. Any other ideas to uncompress this tree are welcome!

Ideally, I would be able to throw this into some tree library like `treelib` to get methods of listing the leaf nodes, accessing data of parents, grandparents, etc.

Comment: I thing it would need only one `for`-loop to convert it and you could do it without any external modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would convert this:

```
l = [
    {"node": "root", "children": ["a"]},
    {"node": "a", "children": ["b", "b"]},
    {"node": "b", "children": ["c", "c", "c"]},
    {"node": "c", "children": ["d"]},
]
```

into a bit more workable format:

```
compressed = {e["node"]: e["children"] for e in l}
```

Then it's quite simple:

```
def expand(compressed, root):
    children = [expand(compressed, n) for n in compressed.get(root, [])]
    return {root: children or "None"}
```

In your example:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(expand(compressed, "root"))
{'root': [{'a': [{'b': [{'c': [{'d': 'None'}]},
                        {'c': [{'d': 'None'}]},
                        {'c': [{'d': 'None'}]}]},
                 {'b': [{'c': [{'d': 'None'}]},
                        {'c': [{'d': 'None'}]},
                        {'c': [{'d': 'None'}]}]}]}]}
```

That said, I would recommend not replacing an empty child list with the string `"None"` and simply have it be an empty list instead (so simply remove the `or "None"` above).

Comment: This is an incredibly elegant recursive approach! My tree will have additional attributes attached to the nodes so your solution only requires a minor modification, thank you!

Comment: @room_temperature Anything to do with trees is almost always easier recursively. Trees are the mother language of recursion.